# How to use GORM for Mongodb in Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, go-gorm

I'm new to `go` and `MongoDB`. I want to connect to MongoDB with GORM in `go-lang`. after a lot of searches, I still can't do it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In short: you can't. [GORM](http://gorm.io/) is created for relational databases, and MongoDB is not a relational but a NoSQL database.

And you can't even use GORM with all SQL databases, the [officially supported list](http://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#Supported-Databases) at the moment is: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite3 and SQL Server, although you can "easily" add support for other SQL servers by [writing GORM dialects](http://gorm.io/docs/dialects.html) for them. But that's the end of it. Adding support for MongoDB would require more work than what your gain would be.

Consider using the [official MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) which is quite mature now. Or if using GORM is a must for you, you must choose another (not MongoDB, preferably one of the above listed supported) database.

Comment: Thanks. However, How can I easily connect to MongoDB in Golang?

Comment: @MohammadGh There are countless examples and tutorials on the internet, and there's an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586592/how-to-perform-addtoset-using-go-official-driver/57587024?r=SearchResults#57587024) as well.

Comment: Is there any ORM (Object–relational mapping) or query builder to connect Cassandra in golang? @icza